FInd the distance between the centers of the circles
In the figure shown, $O$ and $O_1$ are the centers of the circles.
If $r=6$m and $R=8$m,
Calculate the size of $OO_1$(Answer:$10$m)

I think that the upper point of the intersection of the circles would be a point of tangency and thus in the right triangle formed we would have
$OO_1=\sqrt{8^2+6^2} = \sqrt{100} \therefore OO_1 = 10$
but would this point of tangency have to be demonstrated?

To clarify, the information (that distinguishes this step from 2 random circles intersecting) is that from O, there exists a diameter whose endpoints when connected to the intersection points of the circles, intersect on circle $O_1$? $\quad$ If so, while the intersection "should" occur on $OO_1$ by symmetry, that may not be the case.

What do you mean by "point of tangency"?

@jjagmath I believe (though might be reading too much into it) that OP is backing out from the given answer of 10, to claim that $\angle O X O_1 = 90^\circ$, and hence the radius are tangent to the other circle.

@jjagmath  Exactly as the colleague explained

@CalvinLin  The question is exactly as posted in the book... there is no additional information

Then you should edit your question to clarify. Don't make users of the forum read the comments in order to understand your question.

@jjagmath The question is how to solve the problem. My attempted resolution is just an idea I had....The user who solves it will use their own ideas for the resolution...I just included a thought I had

The following is your diagram with several lines and points, in $\color{green}{\text{green}}$, added:

Define
$$\measuredangle FCB = \alpha, \;\; \measuredangle FEB = \beta \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$
Thus, by the Inscribed angle theorem, we have
$$\measuredangle FOB = 2\alpha \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$
Also, $\measuredangle FED = 180^{\circ} - \beta$. Next, since $DEFG$ is a cyclic quadrilateral, then $\measuredangle FGD = \beta$ (opposite angles are supplementary), so by the inscribed angle theorem again, we have $\measuredangle FO_{1}D = 2\beta$. Since $FO_{1}D$ is isosceles (as $\lvert O_{1}F\rvert = \lvert O_{1}D\rvert = r$), this means that
$$\measuredangle O_{1}FD = 90^{\circ} - \beta \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$
By vertically opposite angles, we have $\measuredangle DEC = \beta$ and, as $\measuredangle BDC = 90^{\circ}$ (since $BOC$ is the $O$ circle diameter), then $\measuredangle ECD = 90^{\circ} - \beta$. Thus, using \eqref{eq1A}, we have
$$\measuredangle OCD = \measuredangle FCB + \measuredangle ECD = \alpha + (90^{\circ} - \beta) \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$
Since $\triangle COD$ is isosceles (as $\lvert OD\rvert = \lvert OC\rvert = R$), then $\measuredangle ODC = 90^{\circ} + \alpha - \beta$ also, and
$$\measuredangle DOC = 2\beta - 2\alpha \tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$
Using \eqref{eq2A} and \eqref{eq5A}, we next get
$$\measuredangle FOD = 180^{\circ} - \measuredangle FOB - \measuredangle DOC = 180^{\circ} - 2\alpha - (2\beta - 2\alpha) = 180^{\circ} - 2\beta \tag{6}\label{eq6A}$$
Due to $\triangle FOD$ being isosceles (as $\lvert OF\rvert = \lvert OD\rvert = R$), from \eqref{eq6A} we have
$$\measuredangle OFD = \beta \tag{7}\label{eq7A}$$
This means, using \eqref{eq3A}, that
$$\measuredangle O_1FO = \measuredangle O_{1}FD + \measuredangle OFD = (90^{\circ} - \beta) + \beta = 90^{\circ} \tag{8}\label{eq8A}$$
Thus, your assumption is correct, i.e., $F$ is the point of tangency of $FO_1$ with the circle centered at $O$. As such, just like you've done, using the Pythagorean theorem with $\triangle OFO_1$ leads to your result that
$$\lvert OO_1\rvert = \sqrt{R^2 + r^2} = \sqrt{8^2 + 6^2} = \sqrt{100} = 10 \tag{9}\label{eq9A}$$

Excellent my friend..thanks for help again

We can rephrase the problem in an easier way:

Claim: Let $\omega$ be a circle with centre $O$ and diameter $AB$. Let $X$ and $Y$ be two points on the circle, and let $Z = AX \cap BY$. Prove that $OX$ (similarly $OY$) is tangent to the circumcircle $\odot(XYZ)$.

Proof: $$\measuredangle YXZ = \measuredangle YXA = \measuredangle YBA = \measuredangle YBO = \measuredangle OYB = \measuredangle OYZ$$Hence, we are done by the alternate segment theorem. $\blacksquare$
